# Importance of 2D Polyakov Action and Virasoro Constraints in String Theory

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, spacetime-dimensions, constrained-dynamics

I've been studying the Polyakov action and Virasoro constraints in string theory, and I've come across their specific forms in 2 dimensions (2D):

$$S = -\frac{1}{2} \int d^2 \sigma \sqrt{-det(G_{\alpha \beta})} e^{-2s}$$

$$L_n = \frac{1}{2} \int d^2 \sigma \left( \partial_\alpha X^i \partial^\alpha X^i - n \right) e^{-2s}$$

$$L_0: f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left( \sin(x) + x \cos(x) \right)$$

$$L_1: f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left( e^x - x e^x \right)$$

$$L_2: f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left( e^x - 2x e^x + x^2 e^x \right)$$

$$L_3: f(x) = \frac{1}{6} \left( e^x - 3x e^x + 3x^2 e^x - x^3 e^x \right)$$

Virasoro constraints:

$L_0$ is the Hamiltonian of the string. It is the generator of time translations.

$L_1$ is the momentum of the string. It is the generator of translations along the string.

$L_2$ is the energy of the string. It is the generator of dilations.

$L_3$ is the spin of the string. It is the generator of special conformal transformations.

The equations that describe the interactions of strings with each other

I understand that the Polyakov action and Virasoro constraints are foundational elements of string theory in any number of dimensions. However, I'm particularly interested in understanding the significance of their 2D forms.

My questions are:

- What is the physical and mathematical importance of studying the Polyakov action and Virasoro constraints specifically in 2D?
- How do the 2D forms of these equations relate to key aspects of string theory, such as the consistency of the quantum theory, the critical dimensions, string dynamics, and string perturbation theory?
- How does the 2D worldsheet theory connect to conformal field theory (CFT), and why is this connection important in string theory?
- Are there any unique features or implications of the 2D forms of these equations that don't appear in higher dimensions?

I'd appreciate any insights or references that could help clarify the necessity and significance of the 2D Polyakov action and Virasoro constraints in string theory.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55431/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66948/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic the first link says: This program has so far failed for membranes with internal dimension p>1, so the 2D case above seems novel.

Comment: Note that the worldvolume dimension (including time) is here $p+1$.