# Mode expansion for $p$-branes

Tags: string-theory, quantum-gravity, quantization, branes

In the quantization of $p$-branes, for $p>1$ what is the mode expansion? What I am after, more specifically, is: what is the configuration around which the expansion is made? For example, for the string, the configuration which is expanded around is $X^\mu(\sigma)=\text{const.}$, which is the centre of mass.

Comment: Related: [Why one-dimensional strings, but not higher-dimensional shells/membranes?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55431/2451)